# What does it mean when an optimisation problem has a single solution, no solution or infinitely many solutions?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let's say I have the below function:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2}hx^2 + ix + j$$

and I want to solve the optimization problem:

$$ \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x) $$

How do I find the conditions under which this problem has:

- a unique solution
- infinitely many solutions
- no solution

I've seen the answer, but I don't understand the process and the reasoning. Could anyone help clarify this for me or maybe share some resources on optimization problems that may help me better understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, maybe get some intuition for this problem: 
The problem has

- a unique solution if $h>0$. In this case, the parabola is proper and open at the top. for example like this [image]

Here the minimum exists, it is unique and located at $x = -2/3$. This is because for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(y) \geq f(x)$

- infinitely many solutions when $h = i = 0$. This is the case when there are infinitely many points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}: f(y) \geq f(x)$. For a quadratic function this is precisely the case when it is constant, as seen here.

[image]

- no solution when $h < 0$ or $h = 0$ and $i \neq 0$. This is the case when for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(y) < f(x)$. This can be the case either when the function is linear 
  [image]

or when the parabola is open to the bottom.

[image]

---

Now how did I come up with these conditions? By considering cases.

With such a simple example as a polynomial of second degree in one variable, we may examine the graphs the function induces and by recalling what the definition of minima are.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. That helped a lot, am I right in understanding that there are no solutions for the last 2 cases since for each possible "Minimum" value for y, there exists another x value in the domain that offers a lower value? And so on until infinity, meaning there is no true minimum?

I still struggle though with notation you used saying f(y) < f(x) for example. Isn't f(y) simply just x?

Comment: That is precisely the right understanding. Regarding $f(y)$, we consider the value of the function $f$ at some point $y$ in the domain; we might as well call it $z$.

Comment: Then in the case of $$ h = i = 0 $$ (infinitely many) do we not just write $$ f(y) = f(x) $$ since for all x, y is constant?

Comment: In this specific case we have $f(y) = f(x)$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. But this is only because the function is constant here

Comment: Ok, got it :) Thank you so much for you help and insight!